# Can Cassandra prevent TTL from updating on upsert of table

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra table that is like this...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.data(
    id double,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, data)
) WITH default_time_to_live = 120 AND gc_grace_seconds = 60;
```

My understanding is inserts default to upserts. The problem is according to the docs, upserts still increase the TTL. Short of manually managing this, is there a way to turn off TTL on upsert and just have it updated on insert?

**Possible Solution**

`Using TTL` on the upsert allows overriding the table definition and `TTL(data)` allows us to get the existing TTL. Is a pre select query the only way to do this?